# my compiler is saying that I have an incompatible type. Java

Tags: java

It says that the numbers 125,100 are incompatible types in the line: _die1 = newDie(125,100);

i dont understand it because in the NewDie method it takes int 2 ints, so it should work fine...?! Basically this program creates dice rolls and I am trying to get it to display the roll #2

```
 import java.awt.*;  
// The panel which holds the two dice
import javax.swing.*;
public class DicePanel extends JPanel
{
// instance variables 
private Die _die1, _die2;
private int _roll;


/**
 * Constructor for objects of class DicePanel
 */
public DicePanel()
{
    // initialise instance variables
    super();
    setBackground(Color.GRAY);



    _die1 = new Die(125,100);
    _die2 = new Die(250,100);



    roll();
}
// display the dice in the panel
public void paintComponent(Graphics pen)
{
    super.paintComponent(pen);
    Graphics2D aBetterPen = (Graphics2D)pen;
    _die1.paint(aBetterPen);
    _die2.paint(aBetterPen);



}
// roll both dice and display them
public void roll()
{


   // _die1 = new Two(125,100);
   // _die2 = new Three(250,100);

    _die1 = newDie(125,100); 
   // _die2 = DicePanel.newDie(250,100);
   //repaint();
}
// retrieve the value of each die
public int getDie1()
{
    return _die1.getValue();
}
public int getDie2()
{
    return _die2.getValue();
}

// factory method for a die
public void newDie(int x, int y){

    //_roll = randomNumber(1,6);

    _die1 = new Two(x,y);
    // _die2 = new Three(x,y);

}
// random number generator to return and integer between two integers, inclusive.
public static int randomNumber(int low, int high){
    return low + (int)(Math.random()*(high-low+1));
}
```

}

Comment: There is a method newDie

Comment: Rule 1) The compiler is right; Rule 2) If the the compiler is wrong, see Rule #1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`newDie` returns `void` which is obviously incompatible with `_die`'s type of Die.

Answer (score 1):

There is no line that says `newDie(125,100)`.  There is, however, a line that says `new Die(125,100)` ... and that means something very different.  It is a constructor invocation not a method call.

So either:

- you are calling the `newDie` method, and it is complaining because `newDie` returns `void`, or
- you are invoking the Die constructor as `new Die(125, 100)` and the formal and actual parameter types don't match.

Given the error message is complaining about `125` and `100`, I think the 2nd explanation is the more likely one.  But you didn't include the `Die` constructor declaration in your Question, so I can't be sure.

---

I should also add that `_die1`, `_die2` and `_roll` are coding style violations according to *most* Java coding styles ... and in particular by the coding style that is recommended by Oracle.  You have a good reason for being different (*and personal preference is NOT a good reason*) then you should write your Java code to conform to a mainstream style.

Your code's indentation is also inconsistent with any coding style I've ever seen ... and should also be fixed.

If you are writing code purely for your own benefit, and nobody else is ever going to have to read it, then your code style is your own business.  But if you ever want anyone (e.g. your lecturer, your co-workers, StackExchange readers) to read it, then style is *important*.